# Xcode 8 can't archive "Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1"

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, build, archive

I've got a serious problem on Xcode 8 on macOS Sierra.
when I try to build my app, I get the following issue.

```
CodeSign /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-gnoiiwnelmxzdidnijaswisrwdqe/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app
cd /Users/me/Desktop/MyAppFolder1/MyAppFolder2/MyAppxcode
export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE=/Users/me/Downloads/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
export PATH="/Users/me/Downloads/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Users/me/Downloads/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"

Signing Identity:     "-"

/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign - --timestamp=none /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-gnoiiwnelmxzdidnijaswisrwdqe/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app

/Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-gnoiiwnelmxzdidnijaswisrwdqe/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app: resource fork, Finder information, or similar detritus not allowed
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
```

then I did https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/48905 in the terminal as the following and it worked. but once I clean, the issue comes back.

```
cd /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-gnoiiwnelmxzdidnijaswisrwdqe/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp

ls -al@ *

xattr -c *
```

and this solution doesn't work for archive with the following issue. is there any solution for it?

```
CodeSign /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-gnoiiwnelmxzdidnijaswisrwdqe/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/MyApp/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/MyApp.app
cd /Users/me/Desktop/MyAppFolder1/MyAppFolder2/MyAppxcode
export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE=/Users/me/Downloads/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
export PATH="/Users/me/Downloads/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Users/me/Downloads/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"

Signing Identity:     "iPhone Developer: My Name (**********)"
Provisioning Profile: "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: com.**********.*********"
                  (********-****-****-****-************)

/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign **************************************** --entitlements /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-gnoiiwnelmxzdidnijaswisrwdqe/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/MyApp/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/MyApp.build/Release-iphoneos/MyApp.build/MyApp.app.xcent --timestamp=none /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-gnoiiwnelmxzdidnijaswisrwdqe/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/MyApp/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/MyApp.app

/Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-gnoiiwnelmxzdidnijaswisrwdqe/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/MyApp/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/MyApp.app: resource fork, Finder information, or similar detritus not allowed
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: have you found any solution to this? I downloaded Xcode 8 about 2 weeks ago and signed the very same app with it. a few days ago I've installed macOS Sierra (I had El Capitan before) and now it's not signing the same app.

Comment: Same here, this is driving me crazy. It's only happens if I have a project with  CocoaPods.

Comment: @noisedan no CocoaPods here, also having the problem. I don't think it's related to pods. but it seems project specific. for instance, this is happening to me on my macOS app with no pods, but I have an iOS app with pods and it's signing perfectly.

Comment: Check TimeVision response here, worked for me https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/48905

Comment: @noisedan it solved my issues on debug builds, but now I'm having the exact same problem as the OP: it's failing when I try to archive (which I have to in order to submit to app store)

Comment: It worked for me when I archive the APP few minutes ago. What I did:

1.- Looked for the "bad resources" at the Derived Data APP folder.
2.- Run the script in the icons or anything with the @ at the end.
3.- Cleaned the project and deleted the derived data.
4.- Archived the project.

Comment: This keeps happening on new apps, is this a bug that is going to be fixed?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39863074/4201337 this link is has solved my problem

Answer (score 112):

I found this solution in the Apple forum

```
cd ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
xattr -rc .
```

or

```
xattr -rc ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
```

Comment: Worked for me too on Xcode 8.1 and mac sierra. 
Thank you!

Comment: This worked but I have to do this everytime I create a new app in XCode!

Comment: Fixed my broken Jenkins build on macOS Sierra, XCode 8.2.

Comment: It worked! If anyone wonders what it does - it's a recursive (-r) clear (-c) of Extended Attributes (xattr).

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It seems to be the only solution that's working for most everyone that tries it. Could you also post the link to the Apple Forums page?

Answer (score 21):

Solution 1:

You can try file specific bash command like Mark McCorkle answered.

In terminal, goto project's root directory and execute one by one command

```
  find . -type f -name '*.jpeg' -exec xattr -c {} \;
  find . -type f -name '*.png' -exec xattr -c {} \;
  find . -type f -name '*.tif' -exec xattr -c {} \;
```

Clean Xcode and Re Build. Done.

Solution 2:

You can fix this problem by finding files which holds finder information.

In terminal, goto project root directory and execute

```
ls -alR@ . > kundapura.txt
```

This creates kundapura.txt in current directory. Now search for com.apple.FinderInfo and clear this attributes for all files. You can do it like this

```
xattr -c <filename>
Example: xattr -c guru.png
```

Once you clear all then you are able to code sign. Cheers

Comment: The first solution worked for me on macOS Sierra. It was a problem with the **.png** files. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Solution 1 worked for me as well. Nothing else in this list

Answer (score 12):

For me worked this:

```
cd ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
xattr -dr com.apple.FinderInfo *
```

And then rebuild

Comment: Worked for me on macOS Sierra. Thanks!

Comment: Saver for me. I tried everything.  Running `xattr -c *` also didn't helped.

Answer (score 9):

There is a more permanent fix for this.  Fixing the attributes in the DerivedData works, but the problem keeps coming back.  What you need to do is go to the directory shown when you get the 'resource fork, Finder information, or similar detritus not allowed', the one that contains the .App file.  Then execute...

xattr -lr MyAppName.App

You can then see the resource files that have the attributes that need removing.  Don't remove them from the .App file though, find the original files in your project and open the directory that contains them and execute...

xattr -rc .

This then fixes the ORIGINAL files.  Rebuild should then function ok.  It should also then rebuild properly for archive too.

Comment: this is the only thing suggested here that worked for me! thank you!

Comment: Worked for me. Culprit files where the icon files in Images.xcassets folder.

Comment: Nothing was listed when I ran `xattr -lr MyAppName.app`

Answer (score 6):

This gets caused by some resource files having extra attributes on the file system, probably caused by macOS Sierra (as I started having it after upgrading to macOS Sierra).

Try executing `xattr -c *` on the whole `DerivedData` folder (as stated by the answer in https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/178039#178039):

```
cd ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
xattr -c *
```

Removing attributes only on the build folder fixed the issue for me when debugging. Removing attributes on the whole `DerivedData` folder fixed it for me in archiving too. Please note that it may cause other consequences (albeit highly unlikely), but you can always delete the `DerivedData` folder and it will be regenerated, in case anything gets broken.

Also, if it still fails, cleaning the project (*not* the build folder) after executing the command is a good idea.

Comment: Thanks for explaining - always better to understand what is going on, rather than blindly copy pasting a terminal command.

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem with one file from CocoaPods bundle. 
I've updated CocoaPods to the latest version and run:

```
pod install
```

after that, the problem has gone away.

Comment: Doing this then running Cmd+shift+k (i.e., clean) on my project in Xcode worked for me

Answer (score 3):

in my case issue was with Provisioning Profiles and Account, i fixed by doing these steps:

1. Xcode Preferences ->Accounts->Delete already added account and add it again
2. Generate new Provisioning Profiles and installed in Xcode
3. clean project and rebuild it

Comment: I had this same issue. When I saw in Accounts, it told me session expired login again.

Answer (score 2):

I want to show my answer because it may be of interest (I have wasted a lot of time with this error)

[image: Error screenshot]

None of the previous answers (which have a high score) have been useful to me.

They may be correct, but they haven't solved my problem.

Origin:

**I added a new Target to my iOS application: iMessage**

When I added png images to the Assets. xcassets, the error occurred.

Solution:

Make a copy of png images with "Apple Preview App" and uncheck Alpha.

[image: Preview App screenshot]

Error message disappears.

[image: Preview App screenshot]

Comment: it is really helpful. Solved my issue :) Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

In my case,

Go to

- Xcode preference
- Locations
- Click on Project Path arrow
- In DerivedData folder search for your project name
- Select project folder, Right click and Move to trash

Done!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error on macOS Sierra 10.12.3, Xcode 8.2.
Fixing the *DerivedData* did not work for me.

After I deleted an expired *Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certificate Authority* certificate in *Keychain Access* the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes even if you fixed and/or had correct code-signing done, **the problem might lurk in 3rd-party packages**.

If you closely check out your build error, you might find the name of the 3rd-party libraries on the error message.

In this case, you must build your 3rd-party libraries again. For example in my case, update it via `carthage update` and now the build succeeded properly.