# Replaced resources group in project with resources directory, Codesign failure at build

Tags: ios, swift, code-signing

I was trying to access directories and files loaded locally onto my app, and followed the answer found at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10969555/resource-files-in-subdirectory-are-copied-to-root-directory-of-the-app-bundle).

It told me to create a Resource folder locally within my project directory, and then drag that folder into my project in XCode. Well, I already had a Resource group there that I wanted to replace, so I deleted it. After moving the Resource directory in and building my app, I receive this error:

[image: Codesign Error screen]

I've added the whole resources directory to my build phase copy bundles:

[image: Resource in Copy Bundles]

I've also tried this popular solution to codesign exit errors:

[xattr -rc . within my derived data directory, and root directory of my app.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39449665/xcode-8-cant-archive-command-usr-bin-codesign-failed-with-exit-code-1)

Finally, I've tried deleting my projects derived data, and none of the above seems to work.

This must be some sort of conflict error, like I either didn't get rid of the Resources group (it came with the project when created...) Or I didn't introduce the new resource directory correctly. But, I'm not sure what to do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this by following the solution found here:

[Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37830758/code-signing-error-whenever-i-try-replacing-stock-files-in-new-scenekit-applicat)

Basically I had to recreate the Resources group, drop all of my resources there, then follow the instructions found in the answer of the linked thread. Involved me 1st deleting the derived data folder for the project, then running xattr -rc .  within the project directory.